# cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygnettle-4.dll

Tags: cygwin, cmake

I'm trying to use cmake in cygwin. When doing so I get the following:

```
~> cmake --version
/usr/bin/cmake.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

when I run cygcheck it seems to be missing cygnettle-4.dll (see below), however I can't find any package named cygnettle when running setup-x86.

Any suggestions?

```
~> cygcheck /usr/bin/cmake
C:\cygwin\bin\cmake.exe
  C:\cygwin\bin\cygarchive-13.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cyggcc_s-1.dll
      C:\cygwin\bin\cygwin1.dll
        C:\Windows\system32\KERNEL32.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-RtlSupport-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessThreads-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-Heap-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-Memory-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-Handle-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-Synch-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-File-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-IO-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-ThreadPool-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-LibraryLoader-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-NamedPipe-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-Misc-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-SysInfo-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-Localization-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-ProcessEnvironment-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-String-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-Debug-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-ErrorHandling-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-Fibers-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-Util-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Core-Profile-L1-1-0.dll
          C:\Windows\system32\API-MS-Win-Security-Base-L1-1-0.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cygbz2-1.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cygiconv-2.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cyglzma-5.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cyglzo2-2.dll
cygcheck: track_down: could not find cygnettle-4.dll

    C:\cygwin\bin\cygxml2-2.dll
      C:\cygwin\bin\cygz.dll
  C:\cygwin\bin\cygcurl-4.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cygcrypto-1.0.0.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cyggssapi_krb5-2.dll
      C:\cygwin\bin\cygk5crypto-3.dll
        C:\cygwin\bin\cygkrb5support-0.dll
          C:\cygwin\bin\cygintl-8.dll
      C:\cygwin\bin\cygkrb5-3.dll
        C:\cygwin\bin\cygcom_err-2.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cygidn-11.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cyglber-2-4-2.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cygldap-2-4-2.dll
      C:\cygwin\bin\cygsasl2-3.dll
      C:\cygwin\bin\cygssl-1.0.0.dll
    C:\cygwin\bin\cygssh2-1.dll
  C:\cygwin\bin\cygstdc++-6.dll
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use cygcheck to interrogate the cywgin search database. That is also on the web at http://cygwin.com/packages/

```
 $cygcheck -p cygnettle-4.dll

Found 5 matches for cygnettle-4.dll
cygwin32-nettle-2.7-1 - cygwin32-nettle: libnettle/libhogweed for Cygwin 32bit toolchain (installed binaries and support files)
libnettle4-2.7-1 - libnettle4: A cryptographic library that is designed to fit easily in more or less any context (libnettle runtime) (installed binaries and support files)
libnettle4-2.7-2 - libnettle4: A cryptographic library that is designed to fit easily in more or less any context (libnettle runtime) (installed binaries and support files)
nettle-debuginfo-2.7-1 - nettle-debuginfo: Debug info for nettle (installed binaries and support files)
nettle-debuginfo-2.7-2 - nettle-debuginfo: Debug info for nettle (installed binaries and support files)

exluding debuginfo and cygwinXX cross library
the missing package is 

 libnettle4
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Interestingly Cygwin-Setup thought I already had libnettle4 2.7-2 installed. I re-installed it anyways and also installed libnettle-devel, so I'm not sure which one did it in the end.

Comment: "cygcheck -c |grep Incomplete "    will provide the list of package that are missing some file.

Comment: Do you know where can i get cygnettle-6.dll seems this is a depednency for wget and i cant track this library down anywhere?

Comment: @manakin Have you looked at the ` cygcheck -p cygnettle-6.dll` output ?